# get the current statusline from buffer

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have a plugin that has some functionality that adds some string to the `statusline`. I have a series of functional tests that verify that certain actions produce some output, and would like to verify that, if set, the `statusline` will change after some trigger.

I haven't been able to find something that will allow me to capture (dump?) the rendered contents of the `statusline`. Both the `:help statusline` and `:help status-line` didn't hint to anything that might allow this.

Is there a way to actually do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`:help screenchar()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#screenchar%28%29). With it, you can capture any visible screen cell controlled by Vim (including status lines), and it's main purpose is testing. Its use is a bit clumsy, because you have to query each position individually, and have to explicitly convert back to characters / strings. For example, if the statusline is the second-to-last line, this will get it's first character:

```
:echo nr2char(screenchar(&lines-1, 1))
```

And this will obtain the entire statusline (assuming you don't have any vertical window splits):

```
:echo join(map(range(1, &columns), 'nr2char(screenchar(&lines-1, v:val))'), '')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This totally solves the problem. Had no idea about `screenchar()`

Comment: Yes, it's an obscure low-level command, and only added late in Vim 7.4 or begin of 8.0, if I remember correctly.